# zingchart heatmap not show all hours on y axes

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, heatmap, zingchart

I have 24 hours format values on y axis.I want to display all 24 hours on y-axis.But in heatmap using zingchart display hour in gap of 3 as shown in image.

So,what is the setting required to display all hours on y axes.

[image: heatmap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting the following attributes to adjust the max amount of items visible:

```
scaleX: {
  maxItems : 24,
  itemsOverlap : true
}
```

There is full information in our help center about showing hidden labels on the x-axis -> https://help.zingsoft.com/en/articles/3546391-zingchart-how-to-show-all-labels-on-my-axis